# Having file in hive wareshouse

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a file sample.txt and i want to place it in hive warehouse directory (Not under the database xyz.db but directly into immediate subdirectory of warehouse). Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try moving the file?

Comment: I didn't have env. ready with me.. I found this question in a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, since `/user/hive/warehouse` is just another folder on HDFS, you can move any file to the location without actually creating the file.

From the Hadoop Shell, you can achieve it by doing:

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/hadoop/sample.txt /user/hive/warehouse/
```

From the Hive Prompt, you can do that by giving this command:

```
!hadoop fs -mv /user/hadoop/sample.txt /user/hive/warehouse/
```

Here the first URL is the source location of your file and the next URL is the destination i.e. Hive Warehouse where you wish to move your file.

But such a situation does not generally occur in a real scenario.